# How to run only one GET request for all URL's in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

```
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    console.log(queryObject)
    console.log('getting');
    res.send('hi');
});
```

I want to run this middleware for all GET requests. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into using `.get()` on an express application. You will need to pass your middleware in as a function

```
const middlewareFunction = function() {
  const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  console.log(queryObject)
  console.log('getting');
  next();
}

app.get("*", middlewareFunction);
```

[Express Docs for METHOD](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD)